# How to draw inside table cell in OneNote?

Tags: microsoft-onenote, drawing

Drawings in one note are overlaid on text. So, they do not maintain relations with text. For example, one can't draw inside table cell: drawing will shift away if table resized or something.

Is it possible to overcome this feature?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: Don't use OneNote for this, as it doesn't support object grouping (or anchoring).

Here's [one of many pages](https://web.archive.org/web/20140414180148/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/descapa/archive/2012/07/16/office-2013-customer-preview-is-now-available.aspx) of people begging for it (this one regarding OneNote 2013).

What you are experiencing (IMHO) is basically because the point of OneNote is for taking notes, not for building structured graphical tables, charts and flyers.

That's what Excel, Visio and Publisher are for. :)

A (semi-)workaround:

Use the Lasso tool to select a visible section (of the objects you want grouped), then copy, delete the originals, and paste the lassoed "group" (which is now just a picture of the lassoed objects, not really grouped objects).

[image]

More info on that, and an additional workaround grouping with a table, is discussed here: [OneNote grouping objects : poor workaround for an essential missing feature](https://web.archive.org/web/20151129001549/http://www.line-of-reasoning.com:80/issues/onenote-grouping-objects-poor-workaround-for-an-essential-missing-feature/)